# How to identify array key with value

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a table like below :
[image]

and using below way to calculate result as array

```
while($Br_ROWS = mysql_fetch_assoc($Bracket_Query)){
     $Bracket_Result[] = $Br_ROWS;
}
```

Array result like below :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Guid] => 1
            [Tournament] => 1
            [Position] => A1-1
            [Player] => 123
            [Team] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Guid] => 2
            [Tournament] => 1
            [Position] => A2-1
            [Player] => 325
            [Team] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Guid] => 3
            [Tournament] => 1
            [Position] => B2-1
            [Player] => 325
            [Team] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Guid] => 4
            [Tournament] => 1
            [Position] => A1-2
            [Player] => 235
            [Team] => 
        )

)
```

I Try but don't know how to do it .
**How to specify value of Player when Position is A2-1 (for example)**
**I'm using a wrong way ?**

Comment: why minus to question ?

Comment: you probably got downvote because you did not show what you have tried, why it did not work and what you expected from it. `Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply with `foreach`

```
foreach ($Bracket_Result as $row)
{
   if ($row['Position'] == "A1-2") {
      echo "I found you:".$row['Player'];
   }
}
```

Or you can create a function that return player:

```
function getPlayerbyPosition($players, $position)
{
    foreach ($players as $player)
    {
       if ($player['Position'] == $position) {
          return $player;
       }
    }
}

$result = getPlayerbyPosition($Bracket_Result, "A1-2");
var_dump($result);
```